# server error in PHP Symfony

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am using doctrine for development activity for my project. However in one of the modules I am getting the below error message on my production server. But the error doesn't surface on the development environment

" Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error" "
[image: Server error screenshot]

[image: Development machine view]

Comment: page not found error in the log files

Comment: Please post the error log entry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
./symfony clear:cache
```

Had this problem too and it solved it